# Conditional formula in qlik

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I want to create a condiditional formula for some charts in qliksense.

I want to calculate the average for a KPI `ATD` , if a certain condition of another column is valid, column `W` = 1. So for example:

```
Class  W   ATD
A      1   1
A      1   3
A      0   1
B      1   1
```

Should lead to for class A: `Condi.Avg= 2`

In general it should be then in a new table (for W=1):

```
Class Condi.Avg
A     2
B     1
```

Right now I have:

```
Avg({<W= {1}> ATD)
```

which leads to a column in my charts with `-`:

[image]

How can I change this?

Comment: What kind of chart are you trying to make? What dimensions/measures are you using?

Comment: a table, and I am using other dimensions in that table

Comment: Could you edit your question with comparable fake data? Only column W and ATD isn't really enough to test. I could try and make up some date myself, but then it would be harder to compare. If you do, I'll try and make a working table based on your data.

Comment: I added it, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a typo in your expression.

```
Avg({<W = {'1'}>} ATD)
```

This should provide some result.

Edit (from the author):

```
Avg({< [W] = {'1']>} ATD)
```

is working

Comment: sorry, i posted it wrong, this is the same as I have right now, and also not working

Comment: I also had a typo in my expression!. Please check it after my edit.

Comment: Could you confirm that your ATD field is being handle as a numeric? For instance, do you get any result by doing Avg(ATD)?

Answer (score 1):

As promised, I tried making my own table, here are my results.

Here is my load script:

```
LOAD * INLINE [
   Class, W, ATD
   A, 1, 1
   A, 1, 3
   A, 0, 1
   B, 1, 1
];
```

Then I added a table object with 1 dimension with the field Class, and 1 measure with the expression:

```
Avg({<W={'1'}>}ATD)
```

This results in the following table:

[image]

Which is exactly the same as your expected result:

```
Class Condi.Avg
A     2
B     1
```

It might be the case that one of your other dimensions are interfering with your measure.

Edit from the Author:

```
Avg({<[W]={'1]>}ATD) is working
```